# Is there a property in VBA to detect current month and use it in a string?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some pivot tables where the column filters are "Mar cycle-2020" , "Feb cycle-2020" etc. Every month instead of changing filters in all my pivot tables, i wrote a code like this:

```
Dim current_cycle, last_cycle, last_last_cycle As string
current_cycle = "Mar RPM"
last_cycle = "Feb RPM"
last_last_cycle = "end-Jan rpm"

Sheets("Profit").Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot 1").PivotFields("Version")
     PivotItems(last_last_cycle).Visible = False
     PivotItems(last_cycle).Visible = True
     PivotItems(current_cycle).Visible = True
End With
```

Everytime my pivot sourcesheet gets a new month's data, let's say i got "Apr RPM" today, i have to manually change the string variables `current_cycle, last_cycle and last_last_cycle`. Instead of this, does VBA help in getting current month like the `=MONTH()` function? And append it to my `current_month` , `last_cycle` string and change it from Mar RPM, Feb RPM to Apr RPM, Mar RPM respectively?

Comment: `current_cycle = Format(Date(),"MMM") & " RPM"`

Comment: @ScottCraner - if i have to get last month, do i have to use some offset function for above line? sorry it seems like an easy question but Format(Date()) - 1 didn't work for me.

Comment: `last_cycle = Format(Application.EOMonth(Date(),-1),"MMM") & " RPM"`

Comment: Perfect. Learnt a new property. Thank you